# Sending data from html form to python api then send that data to html

Tags: python, html, flask

So i just started working witih python since it was necessary for this project (because the API im using). So i've struggled with this a bit. I'm trying to send html data from a form to python to then get data from the API and then send it back to another html page so i can see it on my website. I've trying to use flask for this but i can't really get it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Gymnasie arbete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background">
        <div id="top">
            <div id="tab1">
                <button class="button" onclick="location.href='Main.html'">Player search</button>
            </div>
            <div id="tab2">
                <button class="button" onclick="location.href='Champ.html'">Champions</button>
            </div>
            <div id="tab3">
                <button class="button" onclick="location.href='Leaderboard.html'">Leaderboard</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bot"></div>
        <div id="enter">
            <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('summoner') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" id="Username" name="Username" size="60" autofocus placeholder="Username">
            <select name="region"> 
            <option>EUW</option>
            <option>EUNE</option>
            <option>NA</option>
            <option>KR</option>
            <option>BR</option>
            <option>JP</option>
            <option>RU</option>
            <option>LAS</option>
            <option>LAN</option>
            <option>OCE</option>
            <option>TR</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="hello" value="Sök"> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="Main.py"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
from riotwatcher import LolWatcher, ApiError
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
 
#user1 =  0;
#region1 = 0;
 
#app = Flask(__name__) 
 
#@app.route('/summoner')
#def Main():
#    return render_template('Main.html')
 
#@app.route('summoner', methods =['POST'])
#def summoner():
#    user1 = request.form.get['Username']
#    region1 = request.form.get['region']
 
#user =  user1;
#region = region1;
 
user = "TSP";
region = "EUW";
 
if region == 'NA':
    region = 'NA1';
elif region == 'BR':
    region = 'BR1';
elif region == 'LAN':
    region = 'LA1';
elif region == 'LAS':
    region = 'LA2';
elif region == 'OCE':
    region = 'OC1';
elif region == 'KR':
    region = 'KR';
elif region == 'JP':
    region = 'JP1';
elif region == 'EUNE':
    region = 'EUN1';
elif region == 'EUW':
    region = 'EUW1';
elif region == 'RU':
    region = 'RU';
elif region == 'TR':
    region = 'TR1';
 
# global variables
api_key = 'RGAPI-7c42efa5-4720-42cb-82c0-78974b3f57cd'
watcher = LolWatcher(api_key)
my_region = 'EUW1'
 
if region == 'NA1':
    my_region1 = 'AMERICAS';
elif region == 'BR1':
    my_region1 = 'AMERICAS';
elif region == 'LA1':
    my_region1 = 'AMERICAS';
elif region == 'LA2':
    my_region1 = 'AMERICAS';
elif region == 'OC1':
    my_region1 = 'AMERICAS';
elif region == 'KR':
    my_region1 = 'ASIA';
elif region == 'JP1':
    my_region1 = 'ASIA';
elif region == 'EUN1':
    my_region1 = 'EUROPE';
elif region == 'EUW1':
    my_region1 = 'EUROPE';
elif region == 'RU':
    my_region1 = 'EUROPE';
else:
    my_region1 = 'EUROPE';
 
me = watcher.summoner.by_name(my_region, 'TSP')
print(me)
 
# Return the rank status for Doublelift
my_ranked_stats = watcher.league.by_summoner(my_region, me['id'])
print(my_ranked_stats)
 
my_matches = watcher.match.matchlist_by_puuid(my_region1, me['puuid'])
#print(my_matches)
 
m1 = my_matches[0]
#print(m1)
 
# fetch last match detail
#last_match = my_matches['matches'][0]
match_detail = watcher.match.by_id(my_region1, m1)
 
participants = []
for row in match_detail['info']['participants']:
    participants_row = {}
    participants_row['summonerName'] = row['summonerName']
    participants_row['individualPosition'] = row['individualPosition']
    participants_row['championName'] = row['championName']
    participants_row['champLevel'] = row['champLevel']
    participants_row['kills'] = row['kills']
    participants_row['deaths'] = row['deaths']
    participants_row['assists'] = row['assists']
    participants_row['visionScore'] = row['visionScore']
    participants_row['goldEarned'] = row['goldEarned']
    participants_row['item0'] = row['item0']
    participants_row['item1'] = row['item1']
    participants_row['item2'] = row['item2']
    participants_row['item3'] = row['item3']
    participants_row['item4'] = row['item4']
    participants_row['item5'] = row['item5']
    participants_row['item6'] = row['item6']
    participants.append(participants_row)
df = pd.DataFrame(participants)
df
print(participants)
 
#p1 = participants[8]
#print(p1)
```

Heres the my code if that helps.

Comment: You should mention the specific problems that you are facing while running this code. The request.form works for the post method. Also, you might want to change the input tag to button and remove the value=Sok. Is there a reason you passing this specific value?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to reach your goal.

An integration of python files as a script, as you are trying to do, is not easily possible. Furthermore, I am surprised that you are trying to forward the user via javascript. Please use an HTML anchor for this. You can later determine the appearance using a style sheet. Libraries like Bootstrap can help you with this.

My example shows a form for entering all required data. By submitting, the user's entries are sent to the server and stored within the session cookie. The user is redirected to another address. The statistics for the games played are obtained here and then displayed on the page.

##### Flask (app.py)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import (
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    session,
    url_for
)
from riotwatcher import LolWatcher

API_KEY = 'Your api-key here!' # <- !!!
COUNTRIES = ('AMERICAS', 'ASIA', 'EUROPE')
REGIONS = ('BR1', 'EUN1', 'EUW1', 'JP1', 'KR', 'LA1', 'LA2', 'NA1', 'OC1', 'RU')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'your secret here' # <-- !!!

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    keys = ('region', 'name', 'country')
    if request.method == 'POST' and all(k in request.form for k in keys):
        for k in keys:
            session[k] = request.form[k]
        return redirect(url_for('info'))
    return render_template('index.html', regions=REGIONS, countries=COUNTRIES)

def get_match_data(region, name, country):
    watcher = LolWatcher(API_KEY)
    user = watcher.summoner.by_name(region, name)
    matches = watcher.match.matchlist_by_puuid(country, user['puuid'])
    matches = { match:watcher.match.by_id(country, match) for match in matches }
    return matches

@app.route('/info')
def info():
    keys = ('region', 'name', 'country')
    if not all(k in session for k in keys):
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    match_data = get_match_data(*[session[k] for k in keys])
    return render_template('info.html', **locals())
```

##### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="region">Region</label>
        <select name="region" id="region">
          {% for r in regions -%}
          <option value="{{r}}">{{r}}</option>
          {% endfor -%}
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="country">Country</label>
        <select name="country" id="country">
          {% for c in countries -%}
          <option value="{{c}}">{{c}}</option>
          {% endfor -%}
        </select>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

##### HTML (templates/info.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stats Info</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Back</a>
    {% for match, data in match_data.items() -%}
    <h3>{{match}}</h3>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
      <thead><!-- ... --></thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for row in data['info']['participants'] -%}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ row['summonerName'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['individualPosition'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['championName'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['champLevel'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['kills'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['deaths'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['assists'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['visionScore'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['goldEarned'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['item0'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['item1'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['item2'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['item3'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['item4'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['item5'] }}</td>
          <td>{{ row['item6'] }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor -%}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    {% endfor -%}
  </body>
</html>
```

It is not absolutely necessary to store the user data in the session cookie. You can also implement the query and display of game statistics within a single endpoint. I chose this variant to show you the processing of form data with a clearer structure.

To get to know Flask better, I recommend [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).